# How to resolve conflict between 2 laravel packages?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use 2 different laravel packages.
One is Cmgmyr\Messenger and another is syntaxlexx/laravel-5-messenger. syntaxlexx/laravel-5-messenger is based on Cmgmyr\Messenger . I've tried to rename syntaxlexx/laravel-5-messenger Trait. Here is the code of app/User.php

```
namespace App;

use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Traits\Messagable;
use Lexx\ChatMessenger\Traits\Messagable as chat;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasGroups;
    use HasPositions;
    use PivotManger;
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    use HasFactory;
    use Messagable;
    use chat {
        chat::messages as chatMessages;
        chat::threads as chatThreads;
        chat::participants as chatParticipants;
    }
```

But its showing the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Trait method Lexx\ChatMessenger\Traits\Messagable::messages has not been applied as App\User::messages, because of collision with Cmgmyr\Messenger\Traits\Messagable::messages in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/plandental/app/User.php on line 20

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Trait method Lexx\ChatMessenger\Traits\Messagable::messages has not been applied as App\User::messages, because of collision with Cmgmyr\Messenger\Traits\Messagable::messages
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, I resolved the method name collision between two Laravel traits by using the `insteadof` and `as` keywords to specify which trait's method to use and to alias the methods, respectively, in the `User` class.

```
namespace App;

use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Traits\Messagable;
use Lexx\ChatMessenger\Traits\Messagable as ChatMessagable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles, HasGroups, HasPositions, PivotManger, 
        InteractsWithMedia, HasFactory, Messagable, ChatMessagable {
            //Alias methods from ChatMessagable
            ChatMessagable::messages insteadof Messagable;
            ChatMessagable::messages as chatMessages;
            ChatMessagable::threads insteadof Messagable;
            ChatMessagable::threads as chatThreads;
            ChatMessagable::participants insteadof Messagable;
            ChatMessagable::participants as chatParticipants;
    }
}
```